# Trouble getting steady-state solution by solving system of nonlinear algebraic equations in MATLAB

Tags: optimization, matlab, numerical-analysis, ode

**Background**

I have a stiff system of 6 ODEs, represented in MATLAB as follows:

```
system = @(t,x)[x(1,:).*x(2,:).*(-5.726882618492327e8)-x(1,:).*x(3,:).*1.467710449114545e10-x(1,:).*x(4,:).*3.012162507288153e12+x(3,:).*x(6,:).*1.137674873581712e12+x(4,:).*x(6,:).*5.703626484852603e12+x(5,:).*x(6,:).*1.656793950858653e9-x(1,:).^2.*2.980001443206009e8+x(6,:).^2.*8.25e9;x(1,:).*x(2,:).*(-5.726882618492327e8)+x(3,:).*x(6,:).*1.137674873581712e12-x(2,:).^2.*4.476510081133096e2+x(6,:).^2.*3.403491297089207e3;x(1,:).*x(2,:).*5.726882618492327e8-x(1,:).*x(3,:).*1.467710449114545e10-x(3,:).*x(6,:).*1.137674873581712e12+x(4,:).*x(6,:).*5.703626484852603e12;x(1,:).*x(3,:).*1.467710449114545e10-x(1,:).*x(4,:).*3.012162507288153e12-x(4,:).*x(6,:).*5.703626484852603e12+x(5,:).*x(6,:).*1.656793950858653e9;x(5,:).*(-8.186979330234089e8)+x(6,:).*2.1e9+x(1,:).*x(4,:).*3.012162507288153e12-x(5,:).*x(6,:).*1.656793950858653e9;x(5,:).*8.186979330234089e8-x(6,:).*2.1e9+x(1,:).*x(2,:).*5.726882618492327e8+x(1,:).*x(3,:).*1.467710449114545e10+x(1,:).*x(4,:).*3.012162507288153e12-x(3,:).*x(6,:).*1.137674873581712e12-x(4,:).*x(6,:).*5.703626484852603e12-x(5,:).*x(6,:).*1.656793950858653e9+x(1,:).^2.*2.980001443206009e8+x(2,:).^2.*4.476510081133096e2-x(6,:).^2.*8.250003403491297e9];
```

If I use an ODE solver, I can solve the ODE (shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hggLs.png)) and use it to approximate the steady-state solution. As an example,

```
[t,x] = ode15s(system,[0 1e-6],[0 0 0 0 0 1]);
plot(t,x)
ss_sol = x(end,:);
```

For reference, the steady-state solution obtained in this way is approximately

```
ss_sol = [0.322330352943109, 0.458043435766086, 0.001213186698607, 0.000016426443105, 0.157136142002196, 0.061260531336451];
```

Even if I change the initial conditions a bit, I come back to this solution. Note that `sum(ss_sol)` is approximately 1 (the ODEs were derived under this assumption). Also note that due to physical constraints, each variable must be between 0 and 1, which the solution satisfies.

**Problem**

To get the steady-state solution, I'd like to set the derivatives equal to zero and solve the analogous, nonlinear algebraic system for its roots. The system is slightly rewritten in MATLAB as

```
system = @(x)[x(1).*x(2).*(-5.726882618492327e8)-x(1).*x(3).*1.467710449114545e10-x(1).*x(4).*3.012162507288153e12+x(3).*x(6).*1.137674873581712e12+x(4).*x(6).*5.703626484852603e12+x(5).*x(6).*1.656793950858653e9-x(1).^2.*2.980001443206009e8+x(6).^2.*8.25e9,x(1).*x(2).*(-5.726882618492327e8)+x(3).*x(6).*1.137674873581712e12-x(2).^2.*4.476510081133096e2+x(6).^2.*3.403491297089207e3,x(1).*x(2).*5.726882618492327e8-x(1).*x(3).*1.467710449114545e10-x(3).*x(6).*1.137674873581712e12+x(4).*x(6).*5.703626484852603e12,x(1).*x(3).*1.467710449114545e10-x(1).*x(4).*3.012162507288153e12-x(4).*x(6).*5.703626484852603e12+x(5).*x(6).*1.656793950858653e9,x(5).*(-8.186979330234089e8)+x(6).*2.1e9+x(1).*x(4).*3.012162507288153e12-x(5).*x(6).*1.656793950858653e9,x(5).*8.186979330234089e8-x(6).*2.1e9+x(1).*x(2).*5.726882618492327e8+x(1).*x(3).*1.467710449114545e10+x(1).*x(4).*3.012162507288153e12-x(3).*x(6).*1.137674873581712e12-x(4).*x(6).*5.703626484852603e12-x(5).*x(6).*1.656793950858653e9+x(1).^2.*2.980001443206009e8+x(2).^2.*4.476510081133096e2-x(6).^2.*8.250003403491297e9];
```

However, I have trouble getting the same values of `ss_sol` mentioned earlier.

Using `vpasolve`, even when I increase the precision to 100+ digits, does not lead to any solution. Using `fsolve` or `lsqnonlin` (the latter of which lets me set the lower and upper bounds of 0 and 1, respectively) converge to values that are not the steady-state solution, unless I supply `ss_sol` as the initial guess. I try decreasing the tolerances and increasing the number of iterations but still no luck.

Any suggestions? Is the best way really to just integrate the ODEs to steady-state? I keep reading that reducing the stiff system of ODEs to an algebraic equation should be easier to solve, but I just can't find the steady-state solutions this way. I need a general way to solve for the steady-state values for many different systems, so the problem extends beyond the aforementioned specific example.

Answer (score 2):

The problems you are encountering are not unusual.

Nonlinear systems of equations, as you have already
discovered, often have multiple solutions. It can be
difficult to find the specific one you want.

Basic Newton's method is not guaranteed to converge to
*any* solution given a poor initial guess. (I had thought
that the MATLAB/fsolve algorithm would be able to find
*some* solution in this case, however.)

There is a huge body of literature on techniques for solving
nonlinear algebraic equations. A large subset of this literature
deals with algorithms called "continuation methods"  designed
to deal with particularly challenging problems. Many of these
continuation methods are very similar to ODE solution methods!

At this point, I'll assume you are more interested in simply
solving your equations than researching numerical methods.

Here is what I suggest:

If you have a good initial guess, basic Newton's methods will
converge. In your case, it looks like your `ode15s` solution is
approximately steady-state at t=2e-7 which is significantly
before your actual termination time of t=1e-6. Since you only
need an approximate guess, you can probably also reduce the
accuracy of `ode15s` (by setting the options `AbsTol` and `RelTol`)
by at least an order of magnitude. Try calculating an initial
guess by this approach and then passing it to `fsolve` to
calculate the final steady-state solution.

Comment: I should clarify. While `vpasolve` does not converge to a solution no matter the guess I provide, `fsolve` does converge to some solution (it's just that most of them are unphysical and not the steady-state solution from `ode15s`). 

Anyway, thank you so much for your help again. Your suggestion makes a lot of sense. I can certainly try doing that. When others in my field have solved these kinds of problems, they say they use Newton's method (w/ variable-precision arithmetic). That's why I tried using `vpasolve`, but it seems I need to provide a good guess even if the precision is high.

Comment: Variable precision arithmetic will certainly help you improve the accuracy of your solution. But it doesn't change the requirement to have a (relatively) good initial guess for the solution you want.